# Codenameone: AppArg is null on Android Device

Tags: codenameone

I set the recommended build-hints for my Codenameone app to be called from other apps as a share target. But the AppArg in my App is always null on android (8.0.0) when calling my App as a share-target from within another App.

I used this build-hints:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
  <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
  <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
</intent-filter>
```

The app can be selected as a share target on my HUAWEI P-Smart with Android 8.0.0 (and within the android simulator from android studio with Android 8.0.0) - but the parameter send to my app cannot be fetched:

```
disp.getProperty("AppArg", null);
```

returns always null. Regardless if I select a text in the browser and share this text with my app - or if I share a text-file with my App.

In the log of Android Studio I can see, that a selected text is passed to the app:

```
2020-03-20 10:57:50.031 1655-2542/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/plain flg=0xb080001 cmp=de.zeitkuenstlervoll.gtd.gui/.AppStartStub clip={text/plain T:Erkrankung} (has extras)} from uid 10052
```

The text I sent is here: clip={text/plain T:Erkrankung}

I also set the build hint

```
android.activity.launchMode = singleTask
```

Do you have any idea what the reason could be? (By the way: The AppArg ist not null on my iOS-Devices)

Comment: Did you try launching it from a web page to see if the activity was launched with the arguments?
If you have a consistent test case you can extract from this please file an issue with the source code.

Comment: As you can see in my question above the activity is started with the given argument (see log from Android Studio above). The error seems to be, that CN1 is not handling this argument correctly. I will file an issue.

Comment: Issue: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3053